# ある範囲内で整数のインクリメント・デクリメントを循環させるには？

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

「3, 4, 5」という範囲の整数があるとします。カレントロケーションを `5`、インクリメントを `+1` としたとき、`3` を返してほしいです。もし、インクリメントが `+2` なら `4`、`+7` であれば `3` のように、3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3... とインクリメントの結果が循環してほしいです。

**やってみたこと** :

+1、-1 のインクリメント/デクリメントの場合は下記のコードで実装できましたが、+2 や -4 など加減数が 1 を超える場合に対応させようとすると、方法がわからなくなります（下記の関数を加減数ぶんfor文で繰り返し実行することはできますが……）。

実装

```
NSUInteger NSRangeIncrementLocationInRange(NSUInteger location, NSRange range) {

  NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange: range];

  if (![indexSet containsIndex: location]) {
    return NSNotFound;
  }

  NSUInteger index = [indexSet indexGreaterThanIndex: location];

  return index != NSNotFound ? index : [indexSet firstIndex];
}

NSUInteger NSRangeDecrementLocationInRange(NSUInteger location, NSRange range) {

  NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange: range];

  if (![indexSet containsIndex: location]) {
    return NSNotFound;
  }

  NSUInteger index = [indexSet indexLessThanIndex: location];

  return index != NSNotFound ? index : [indexSet lastIndex];
}
```

実行例

```
// 4 〜 8の範囲内で8をインクリメントする
NSLog(@"%zd", NSRangeIncrementLocationInRange(8, NSMakeRange(4, 5))); // 8の次は最小値に戻って4が返る
```

**求めているもの** :

理想的なのは下記のような関数で、

```
NSUInteger NSRangeIncrementLocationInRange(NSUInteger location, NSInteger increment, NSRange range);
```

`increment` に `3` だの `-8` だの正負どちらでも渡せるようにしたいです。

**質問** :

このようなメソッド、または関数は、Objective-C、またはCのフレームワークやライブラリに存在しますか？　もしない場合、実装するためにどのようなコードが考えられますか？

Comment: 要素の個数の剰余系で個数以内の数に納めることができると思います。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY なるほど。ちょっとやってみます

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cっぽく書けば下記コードで算出できます。一度`range`で剰余(`%`)を求めたあと、負値に対処するため再び`(N + range) % range`を行っています。

```c
// 値(value+diff)を範囲[rl, rh)にマッピング
int f(int value, int diff, int rl, int rh)
{
  int range = rh - rl;
  return (((value + diff - rl) % range) + range) % range + rl;
}
```

入力値`value`の範囲チェックはしていませんので、必要ならば別途追加してください（要不要は要件によると思います）。

LiveDemo: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4gUve20aihTOVhuz

Comment: どもです。4から8までの範囲で、5から-2する場合は `f(5, -2, 4, 8)` で合っていますか？　これで期待する結果は `8` ですが `7` になってしまいます。

Comment: 半開区間で指定する仕様になっていますので、この実装を維持する場合は`f(5, -2, 4, 9)`となります。

Comment: 「半開区間」を初めて知りました。よくみるとコメントの `[rl, rh)` の部分で示してあるのですね。

Comment: ただ、それでも `7` が返ってきてしまいます。そちらでは `8` になりますか？　こちらの環境がおかしいのかな。

Comment: ごめんなさい。コードがバグってました。s/`(value + diff)`/`(value + diff - rl)`/

Comment: そうでしたか。修正されたコードを試してみると期待した答えが返ってきました。また、大きな絶対値の `increment` によって何巡しても問題ないようです。

Answer (score 1):

自己回答です。

**`location` を基点に加減するべき数（距離）を求める** 解法です。

```
NSUInteger NSRangeIncrementLocationInRange(NSUInteger location, NSInteger increment, NSRange range) {

  if (!NSLocationInRange(location, range)) {
    return NSNotFound;
  }

  BOOL incrementIsPositive = increment >= 0;
  NSUInteger distance = ABS(increment) % range.length;

  NSInteger result = location;
  result += incrementIsPositive ? distance : -distance;

  if (!NSLocationInRange(result, range)) {
    result += incrementIsPositive ? -range.length : range.length;
  }

  return result;
}
```

**解法** :

- インクリメントの増減値を整理する（周回数を取り除く） : `incrementの絶対値 % range.length`
- `location` に増減値を加算（インクリメントが正なら加算、負なら減算）
- `result` が範囲外なら `range.length` を加算または減算して範囲内で1周させる

Comment: `range.location`を参照していないのはまずいと思います。`(location + increment - range.location) % range.length + range.location`のようになるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。そのコードのほうがスマートですね！　ひとつ疑問なのですが、「`range.location` を参照していないのはまずい」は、何がまずいのでしょうか。範囲外の `location` を入れた場合にまずそうだな、と考えたのですが、それはどちらのコードでも同じでした。`location` が範囲内であれば `range.location` を利用しなくても正しい値を返すようなのですが。ただ単に自分が書いたような意図が見えにくい回りくどいコードになってしまうってことでしょうか。

Comment: @pgrho あれ？　そのコードは負の `increment` に対応してますか？　コメントを反映した回答は一度ロールバックします

Comment: じぶんのコードでも負の `increment` で循環する場合に正しい結果が返りません。 `NSLog(@"%zd", NSRangeIncrementLocationInRange(5, -2, NSMakeRange(4, 5))); // 3（8でなければならない）`

Comment: range.locationに対する注意喚起のつもりだったので負数の対応はしていませんでした。誤解させてしまったのであれば申し訳ありません。

Comment: @pgrho そうでしたか。自己回答ではrange.location単体を意識しなくても答えを得られてしまったのですが、コードは長くなってしまいました。

Comment: 最終的な自己回答へ修正しました。

Answer (score 1):

デクリメントのほうなんですけど、整数値が環状に並んでいるというイメージをしてください。（下図）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
2戻るということは、3進むのと同じです。これを、一般化して表現すると、increment**戻る**ということは、range.length - increment**進む**とおなじであることに気づくはずです。さらに厳密に表現すると、range.length - increment % range.length進むと同じです。これをそのままインクリメント（increment > 0）のときの式に代入してやります。具体的にコードにすると、こうなります。

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSUInteger NSRangeIncrementLocationInRange(NSInteger location, NSInteger increment, NSRange range) {
    NSUInteger result;
    // locationがrangeの範囲外なら、NSNotFoundを返す。
    if (!NSLocationInRange(location, range)) return NSNotFound;
    if (increment > 0) { // incrementが正数の場合。
        result = (location - range.location + (NSUInteger)increment) % range.length + range.location;
    } else if (increment == 0) { // incrementが0の場合、locationをそのまま返す。
        result = location;
    } else { // incrementが負数の場合。range.lengthとincrementの差を、locationに加えるという計算をする。
        result = (location - range.location + (NSUInteger)((NSInteger)range.length + increment % (NSInteger)range.length)) % range.length + range.location;
// ((NSInteger)range.length + increment)) % range.length + range.location; 修正しました。
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSUInteger inc = NSRangeIncrementLocationInRange(5, -8, NSMakeRange(4, 5));
        NSLog(@"Result = %ld", inc);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

編集しました。
引数incrementの型を、NSUIntegerからNSIntegerに変えました。きわめて初歩的な間違いですね。ご容赦。暗黙的に型キャストしてくれるであろう箇所も、明示的に型キャストしました。

二度目の編集をしました。負の向きに1巡以上するincrementで、正しい結果にならないという指摘を受けて、修正しました。
「increment**戻る**ということは、range.length - increment**進む**とおなじ」を、
「increment**戻る**ということは、range.length - increment % range.length**進む**とおなじ」に変更しました。

三度目の編集をしました。
「整数値を環状に並べる」を、図にして、わかりやすくしました。

Comment: 一番はじめに自己回答したものに解法の説明を追記しました。この回答の解法は、整数値が環状に並ぶイメージとあるように、じぶんのとは若干異なるように見えるのですが、解法に違いがある場合はその点を比較できるよう解説の追記をお願いできないでしょうか。結果的に同じ答えが出るものも解法が異なれば参考になります。

Comment: 「increment戻るということは、range.length - increment進むとおなじである」の一文で、解法の違いを説明できていると思いますが？

Comment: もうひとつ、じぶんも含めて他の方のもなのですが、負の方向へ循環するときに期待する答えが返ってきません。`NSRangeIncrementLocationInRange(5, -2, NSMakeRange(4, 5)); // 4（8が期待される）`

Comment: 正直に言うと、それが何を言っているのかよく分からないのですが、回答者さんがそれで十分説明しているとおっしゃるのであればこれ以上は求めません。

Comment: 引数incrementの型をNSUIntegerからNSIntegerに変更しました。負数をとる可能性があるのに、NSUIntegerでは、なにやってんだか、ですね。すみません。

Comment: じぶんも型は見落としていました。修正後は循環が一度であれば正しい値を返してくれます。ただ、`(5, -8, NSMakeRange(4, 5))` のように2巡するとだめでした（`7` を期待するが `8` が返ってくる）。じぶんのコードでも負の方向への循環でバグるのでちょっと考えてみます。

Comment: ご指摘を受けて、再修正しました。

Comment: 二度目の修正後は何巡しても問題なくなりました。解読しながら学習させていただきます。ベストアンサーは正しく動作するコードを仕上げた先着順ということでご容赦を。どちらも助かりました。